# How to echo a value from another table inner joined with the current table

Tags: php, mysql

I have a simple problem that I couldn't get my head around it 
the problem is I'm trying to echo a value from **status** table inner joined with the current table *`user_asset`* by status's id *`s_id`*

I want to echo the name of the status but it keeps showing me this error

> Notice: Undefined index: stat in D:\wamp64\www\Caprabia-test\admin.php
>   on line 104

```
=============================================
|                user_asset                 |
=============================================
| id | category | code | userid | status_id | 
=============================================

====================
|   status table   |
====================
| s_id | stat_name |
====================

===========================
|   category table        |
===========================
| category_id | cate_name |
===========================

=============================================================================
|                                  user                                     |
=============================================================================
| user_id | first_name | last_name | email | password | dept | user_type_id |
=============================================================================
```

Here is my **php code** :

```
$result = mysqli_query(
    $conn, 
    "select 
         user_asset.*, 
         user.first_name as fname, 
         user.last_name as lname,
         user.user_id, 
         user.dept,
         category.cate_name as titlecat, 
         status.stat_name as stat 
    from user_asset     
    inner join category on user_asset.asset_category = category.category_id     
    inner join user on user_asset.userid = user.user_id 
    inner join status on user_asset.status_id = status.s_id"
);
```

and **my table** :

```
<table cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0" border="0" class="datatable-1 table table-bordered table-striped  display " width="100%">
    <thead>
        <tr >
            <th style="text-align:center"> الرقم </th>
            <th style="text-align:center">المستخدم</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">القسم</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">الصنف</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">الكود</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">التفاصيل</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">الحالة</th>
            <th style="text-align:center">لاعدادات </th>
        </tr>
    </thead>
    <tbody>

    <?php 
    $no = 1;
    while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
    ?>

        <tr>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $no;?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center">
                <a href="/Caprabia-test/view_user.php?id=<?php echo $row['user_id'];?>">
                    <?php echo $row['fname'];?>  <?php echo $row['lname'];?> 
                </a>
            </td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['dept'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['titlecat'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['code'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['title'];?></td>
            <td style="text-align:center"><?php echo $row['stat'];?></td>
            <td class="center" style="text-align:center">
                <a class="" href="edit_asset.php?idedit=<?php echo $row['asset_id'];?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title=" تعديل الاصل" > 
                    <i class="icon-edit"> </i>
                </a>
                <br>
                <a class=""href="move_asset.php?idmove=<?php echo $row['asset_id']?>" data-toggle="tooltip" title="نقل الأصل الى مستخدم اخر"> 
                    <i class="icon-move"> </i>
                </a>
                <br>
                <a class="" href="admin.php?idedelete=<?php echo $row['asset_id'] ?>"  onclick= "return checkDelete()" data-toggle="tooltip" title="ارشفة الاصل"> 
                    <i class="icon-trash"> </i>
                </a>
            </td>
        </tr>

        <?php $no++; ?>
    <?php }?>

    </tbody>
</table>
```

The output of `var_dump($row)` :

```
array (size=22)
    0 => string '1210' (length=4)
    'asset_id' => string '1210' (length=4)
    1 => string '9' (length=1)
    'asset_category' => string '9' (length=1)
    2 => string '564' (length=3)
    'code' => string '564' (length=3)
    3 => string 'ىلاةةيلاةلا' (length=22)
    'title' => string 'ىلاةةيلاةلا' (length=22)
    4 => string '19001' (length=5)
    'userid' => string '19001' (length=5)
    5 => string '1' (length=1)
    'status_id' => string '1' (length=1)
    6 => string 'احمد' (length=8)
    'fname' => string 'احمد' (length=8)
    7 => string 'نور' (length=6)
    'lname' => string 'نور' (length=6)
    8 => string '19001' (length=5)
    'user_id' => string '19001' (length=5)
    9 => string 'تقنية المعلومات' (length=29)
    'dept' => string 'تقنية المعلومات' (length=29)
    10 => string 'أجهزة كهربائية' (length=27)
    'titlecat' => string 'أجهزة كهربائية' (length=27)
```

Comment: Can you add `var_dump($row)` after `while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){` to check what you got ?

Comment: What does your category table look like?

Comment: category table = category_id | cate_name @Johanne

Comment: @MickaëlLeger this is what I got `array (size=22)
  0 => string '1210' (length=4)
  'asset_id' => string '1210' (length=4)
  1 => string '9' (length=1)
  'asset_category' => string '9' (length=1)
  2 => string '564' (length=3)
  'code' => string '564' (length=3)
  3 => string 'ىلاةةيلاةلا' (length=22)
  'title' => string 'ىلاةةيلاةلا' (length=22)
  4 => string '19001' (length=5)
  'userid' => string '19001' (length=5)
  5 => string '1' (length=1)
  'status_id' => string '1' (length=1) and so on`

Comment: @AhmadTariq ... and your user table

Comment: the "and so on"...likely contains the information we were looking for. Edit your question (instead of pasting into the comments) the full var_dump output of your row.

Comment: @ADyson I've edited it

Comment: @MickaëlLeger please take a look at it now

Comment: Thanks. I don't see why it would randomly omit the last field from the query. It's a bit strange. Are you sure you're running the correct version of the code? If you run that query direct in MySQL Workbench or phpMyAdmin (or whatever database tool you use) does it produce the right result?

Comment: yes it produces the results @ADyson

Comment: Ok. Well unfortunately, unless someone else sees something I've missed, I don't see how it's possible for the code you've shown to produce the output you've shown. There's no reason for it not to output that column.

Comment: But just as an experiment, please try moving that column earlier in your select clause, and see if it outputs it then. Just in case there's some issue with it being the last column. I don't know what that issue is (there shouldn't be one) but it's just worth trying

Comment: ok I have cloned the table category and renamed it to stat and moved the columns in select clause then finally it worked thank's @ADyson me too I couldn't find any errors in the coding

Comment: As you can see, in your `var_dump($row)` you have no `$row['stat']`, that's why you have this error

Comment: @ADyson is it possible to inner join more then 2 tables to display them in 1 table, for example, there is a user from **user** table `Ali` inner joined with dept from **dept**  table `IT`  and there is also `user_asset` table inner joined with **user** table therefore I want to show the department name in a table fetched from **user_asset** table